# SQL - JOIN of JOIN / UNION of joins

Tags: sql, join, union

Consider the following SQL database architecture that represents a sport club :[image: database architecture]

Parents (PARENT) have kids (KID) that are team (TEAM) members (MEMBERS). Parents may also be team administrator (ADMIN). Note that :

- administrators don't necessary have kids in the teams ;
- parents with kids in the team are not necessary team administrator ;
- kids may be in several teams.

Given a PARENT.id_parent, how can I select the list of TEAM.id_team linked to this parent (administrator, just parent or both). Each TEAM.id_team must be unique, even if the parent has kids in the team AND is administrator.

The following gives me the teams linked to the parents via child:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT TEAM. * 
FROM TEAM
INNER JOIN MEMBERS ON MEMBERS.id_team = TEAM.id_team
INNER JOIN KID ON KID.id_kid = MEMBERS.id_kid
WHERE KID.id_parent = 1
```

This one gives me the teams where the parent is administrator:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT TEAM . * 
FROM TEAM
INNER JOIN ADMIN ON ADMIN.id_team = TEAM.id_team
WHERE ADMIN.id_parent = 1
```

But I don't know how to get the union (or join ?) of both.

Comment: Please add the query you've tried so far along with some sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: You don't need to join Parent table in 2nd query as Admin table itself contains relevant Parent ids. Also to merge both result, just use UNION between both queries.

Comment: PARENT is joined in both queries ? I'm completely lost, I'll take a break ... :-)

Comment: As u wish.....but I think the answer given below should work. Try it once.

Comment: What do you mean by *merge both of them*? *Append* with `UNION` (vertical bind) or *merge* with `JOIN` (i.e., horizontal bind)?

Comment: Vertical or horizontal bind don't speak to me. That's probably the point of my question. All I want is a list of TEAM.id_team linked to a given parent PARENT.id (administrator, just parent or both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be an optimized way of doing it (to do that I'll need to know the table sizes and other nuances in the database). but I think this would give you what is required (because u don't need team name)

```
select distinct a.parent_id, b.id_team
from parent as a
left join admin as b
  on a.parent_id = b.parent_id

UNION --this will remove duplicates

select distinct a.parent_id, c.id_team
from parent as a
left join kid as b
  on a.parent_id = b.parent_id
left join members as c
  on b.id_kid = c.id_kid
```

Comment: You're the best.